# How can I build a program with shadow stacks?

Tags: cfi, shadowstack

CLANG has [CFI](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ControlFlowIntegrity.html) and Microsoft has [CFG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-flow_integrity) but is there any readily available way to build a binary with a shadow stack? I would like to try it out but could not find anything.

Comment: Why the close vote?

Comment: I don't know. It seems perfectly on-topic to me.

Comment: I haven't looked into how it works, but what about clang's SafeStack?